# Seaside Smalltalk & jQuery UI Accordion - huge height

Tags: jquery, height, accordion, smalltalk, seaside

I have a problem. I would like to make a site in Seaside Smalltalk which would display methods of all subclasses of Collection in a jQuery UI Accordion. I've developed two methods:

```
renderContentOn: html 
html div script: html jQuery new accordion;

    with: [(self elements: html)
            keysAndValuesDo: [:t2 :t3 | 
                html
                    div: [html anchor: t2].
                html div
                    with: [html paragraph: t3]]]

elements: html 
| dict |
dict := Dictionary new.
Collection withAllSubclasses
    do: [:e | dict
            at: e asString
            put: [html orderedList list: e methodDict]].
^ dict
```

Everything is working fine except one thing: the height of the containing divs is horribly high: 7000px. I've no idea what is causing that, and I need help.

UPDATE:
I'm using Seaside 3.0.7. These styles are set inline. The two files I've provided are everything I use. The text takes about 1/10 place of the div, the rest is just empty space.

Comment: Is there enough content in the div to make it that high? I mean, is the problem that there is no scroll bar?

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear enough: the text takes about 1/10 place of the div, the rest is just empty spce. I looked into the source and the div is set to 7000px. If I disable it (the height element) in Chrome inspector, everything is ok. I don't know hot to tell Seaside to not code this 'height: 7000px'.

Comment: Could you give us some more details? Which version of Seaside are you using, are you including any css / js files? Are the 7000px set as inline style or in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit outdated but as there is still no answer:

add autoHeight: false to your accordion creation. auto-height: true, which is default sizes all Compartments the same height.

```
html div script: (html jQuery new accordion
               autoHeight: false );
```